# change bean refrence object in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Below is my jsp i have create bean e and try to assign e2 to e which are same type. JSP compiled without any error but when i tried to get property from bean (e) it show assignment (e = e2) not worked.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Vector" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>
<%@ page import="FAHsep.beans.Employee2" %>
<%@ page import="FAHsep.beans.Employee" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<jsp:useBean id="e" class="FAHsep.beans.Employee2"/>
<html>
<body>
    <b>Current Employees</b>
    <ul>
        <%
            Vector v = (Vector) request.getAttribute("list");
            Iterator i = v.iterator();
            Employee2 e2 = (Employee2) i.next();
            e = e2;
                %>
        <li>
            <jsp:getProperty name="e" property="firstName" />
            <jsp:getProperty name="e" property="lastName"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating bean in scriptlet does not update bean in page context which  used.
So As an temp solution I used below line to update page context by my self. Please let me know if you have better solution.

```
Vector v = (Vector) request.getAttribute("list");
Iterator i = v.iterator();
Employee2 e2 = (Employee2) i.next();
e = e2;
pageContext.setAttribute("e", e);
```